# Tengo un formulario con un input de correo, pero no tiene funcionamiento

Tags: javascript, html

Buen dia comunidad, quiero saber si me pueden ayudar, tengo un input de correo electronico en mi portafolio, la funcionalidad es que las personas que necesiten saber de mi dejen su correo y yo pueda responder, pero no sé como darle esa funcionalidad. Me podrian orientar? estoy utilizando JavaScript como lenguaje

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con funcionalidad, que puedan llegarte los correos electrónicos escritos en dicho input?

Comment: asi es, quiero que me lleguen a mi, mira https://memobrown.com si entras y pones tu correo no hace nada

Comment: Requieres del lado del backend programarlo, con nodejs si será puro JS o PHP por ejemplo o simplemente en el HTML trabajando con mailto (esto último sería lo mas simple)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quieres seguir haciendo todo con JS puedes probar [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/products/realtime-database)

unicamente seria completar la conexion con tu proyecto en firebase y hacer algo asi `firebase.database().ref().child('emails').push("alguien@mail.com");`

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas un lenguaje del lado del servidor para el tratamiento de datos como Node o PHP, puedes usar la función mail() de PHP, recuerda que la función de correo no funcionará en un ambiente local.

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Puedes encontrar más en la documentación de PHP: https://www.php.net/manual/es/tutorial.forms.php

Comment: NodeJS no es un lenguaje de programación